# How to unlock iPhone for Photos App after accidntally pressing "Do not allow"

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, photos.app

Usually the "positive" / assent button is on the right. But in the case of "Allow" / "Do not allow" it is on the left. So I hit the wrong one.  How do I get that "choice" back?  I closed the *Photos* App and it is now happy to let me retry:

[image]

But on the iPhone it does not ask me again. So is there a settings list to remove the "blocked" apps in the iOS/iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually disconnecting USB cable is enough to prompt to trust a device. Apple has a nice list of things to try when the database that tracks this gets in a state where you don’t get the prompts or control you wish:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202778

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and award this. What actually happened?  I had to try a number of times reconnecting before iOS gave me a chance to try again.  No idea what made it finally bestow that favor